# @Autowired(required=false) bean is null when called from another module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have two classes, let's say A and B. A is in module 1 and B is in module 2. Module 1 is compiled in module 2. There is a bean autowired in class A with required=false.

```
@Service
public class A implements X{
    @Autowired(required=false)
    private C objectC;
    public String method(){
      //does some processing with methods by objectC.
    }
}
```

class A is autowired in class B in module 2.

```
@Service
public class B implements Y{
    @Autowired 
    private A objectA;
    public String method(){
       return objectA.method();
    }
}
```

Now, the issue is, when method() of class A is called from class B, the autowired(required=false) object is not injected. While the same object is properly injected when the same method is called from another class within the same module, it is not injected when called from another module.

Comment: looks like you've missed to declare it `final`

Comment: @im_infamous how does final save the problem here? can you please explain

Comment: Because `@Autowired` doesn't care to inject beans for your non-final fields afair

Comment: Can you give the error logs as well?

Comment: @im_infamous, Autowired does inject beans, irrespective of final or non final field. In this case, since it is set to false, it will not auto inject the bean

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-high-performance/9781788838382/f7b7d332-c80d-4cd1-87b1-d7b5e1b146a0.xhtml

Comment: I've slightly misspelled: "it won't be injected". I've ran into the issue when injected bean apparently ended up being null and thus service fired npe at runtime

Comment: @SamarthJuneja your intuition of the oreilly.com post is wrong. if there is a bean, it will be autowired whether it is *required=false/true*. `@Autowired(required=false)` tells to the container to **inject** the bean if found or leave it(optional autowiring)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is while scanning your packages. `@Autowired(required=false)` tells to the container to **inject** the bean if found or continue without it (optional autowiring).

So, in *module 2* you have to check that the packages of *module 1* are being properly scanned. The `@Autowired` has no problem.

For instance:

```
class ClassA {
    @Autowired 
    private Dependency1 dependency1;
    @Autowired(required=false) 
    private Dependency2 dependency2;
    @Autowired(required=false) 
    private Dependency3 dependency3;
}
```

The following are allowed combinations of dependencies for `ClassA`:

1. *Dependency1*
2. *Dependency1,  Dependency2*
3. *Dependency1, Dependency3*
4. *Dependency1, Dependency2, Dependency3*

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that in your code you're not writing something like

```
A a = new A();
```

? Because if you do so the autowired object will be null.
Please use ObjectProvider for your test like this:

```
@Autowired
ObjectProvider<A> provider;
 

if(provider.getIfAvailable()!=null)
provider.getIfAvailable().method();
```